# How to get 1024 FFT bins from 600 shorts audio buffer. JAVA Android

Tags: java, android, fft, bins

I have gone through different questions in SO for this, but couldnt get answer for this. 
How can I get 1024 fft bins from a data of 600 shorts audio buffer. If yes/no please explain.

Comment: Which FFT implementations have you tried?

Comment: @Michael - the question has to do with the fundamental idea of the Fourier transform itself, *independent* of the use of the FFT optimization for calculating it, or any particular implementation thereof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zero-pad your data by appending 424 zeros (shorts) to the data in your buffer (or perhaps prepending 212 zeros and postpending 212 zeros if you care about phase).  This composite data vector of length 1024 will produce 1024 FFT result bins from an FFT of length 1024.